Comparing Multiple Values Across Columns of Pandas Dataframe Based on Column Names
I have a pandas dataframe with a number of thresholds and values associated with epochs. I want to compare the all of the thresholds with their associated values simultaneously to remove rows as needed. I will be doing this many times and the letter designations can change each time I create this dataframe, but there will always be a 1:1 association for threshold and value. The number of thresholds and values can change each time the dataframe is created though. The end goal is to get all of the epochs where all of the values are below their respective thresholds. The sample below does not have any that fit this requirement, but I've included it so people have a visual for what I'm working with. For now, how would I do this comparison in an efficient way?
            epoch  thresholdA  thresholdB  thresholdC  thresholdD  thresholdE  thresholdF  thresholdG      valueA    valueB    valueC      valueD    valueE    valueF     valueG
0   1723489899000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  0.292969   0.00000  19.775391
1   1723489900000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  0.292969   0.00000  19.775391
2   1723489901000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  0.292969   0.00000  19.775391
3   1723489902000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.780273  2.929688   0.00000  31.054688
4   1723489903000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.780273  2.929688   0.00000  31.054688
5   1723489904000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.780273  2.929688   0.00000  31.054688
6   1723489905000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
7   1723489906000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
8   1723489907000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
9   1723489908000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
10  1723489909000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
11  1723489910000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  31.347656
12  1723489911000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  37.500000
13  1723489912000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  37.500000
14  1723489913000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -3.828125 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  37.500000
15  1723489914000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  40.869141
16  1723489915000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  40.869141
17  1723489916000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  299.311523 -4.785156 -2.841797  199.541016  2.929688   0.00000  40.869141
18  1723489950000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   3.222656
19  1723489951000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   3.222656
20  1723489952000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   3.222656
21  1723489953000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   0.439453
22  1723489954000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   0.439453
23  1723489955000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   0.439453
24  1723489956000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.585938
25  1723489957000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.585938
26  1723489958000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.585938
27  1723489959000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.439453
28  1723489960000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.439453
29  1723489961000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   0.439453
30  1723489962000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   1.171875
31  1723489963000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   1.171875
32  1723489964000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   1.171875
33  1723489965000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   5.566406
34  1723489966000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   5.566406
35  1723489967000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   5.566406
36  1723489968000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   6.005859
37  1723489969000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   6.005859
38  1723489970000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   6.005859
39  1723489971000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   4.687500
40  1723489972000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   4.687500
41  1723489973000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -3.828125 -2.841797  129.677750  2.929688  81.37207   4.687500
42  1723489974000          30         120          30          30         120          30           2  199.301758 -4.785156 -2.841797  129.677750  0.292969  81.37207   4.833984


Here's one approach:

Use df.filter for both 'value*' and 'threshold*' columns. For 'threshold*', chain df.values to allow element-wise comparison on shape, rather than on column labels.
Afterwards check df.all row-wise (axis=1) and use for boolean indexing.

Minimal reproducible example
import pandas as pd

data = {'epoch': {0: 1723489899000, 1: 1723489900000}, 
        'thresholdA': {0: 30, 1: 30}, 'thresholdB': {0: 120, 1: 120}, 
        'valueA': {0: 299.311523, 1: 10}, 'valueB': {0: -4.785156, 1: -4.785156}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

           epoch  thresholdA  thresholdB      valueA    valueB
0  1723489899000          30         120  299.311523 -4.785156 
1  1723489900000          30         120   10.000000 -4.785156

# aim: delete row 0, since valueA >= thresholdA

Code
m = (df.filter(regex=r'^value') < df.filter(regex=r'^threshold').values).all(axis=1)

df[m]

           epoch  thresholdA  thresholdB  valueA    valueB
1  1723489900000          30         120    10.0 -4.785156

N.B. The above assumes not just a "1:1 association for threshold and value", but also that the columns occur in the same order. If not, you should sort them first.
